# Speed up AJAX search in UL LI list with more than 5000 objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, search

Stack community,

Im having simple Ajax js search using .addClass and .removeClass because I found out its faster than .show() and .hide().

Problem is, it's still not fast enough and I'm totally lost.

Search can be found [here](https://powerparts.cz/adaptery-k-notebookum/9-nabijecka-na-notebook-asus-lenovo-msi-toshiba-19v-342a-55x25#idTab_dm_newtab)

The actual code looks like this: [Edit fiddle - JSFiddle - Code Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/fgfjo2n9/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Schovat pocet pri nacteni
  $("#vyhledavani_kompatibilit_pocet").hide();

  $("#vyhledavani_kompatibilit_input").keyup(function() {

    // Zobrazit pocet po napsani nejakeho vysledku
    $("#vyhledavani_kompatibilit_pocet").show();
    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(),
      count = 0;

    var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
    if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {

      // Loop through the comment list 
      $(".komp").each(function() {

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          $(this).addClass("schovatDiv");
          if ($(this).siblings(':hidden')) {
            $(this).parent().prev().addClass("schovatDiv");
          }


          // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
          $(this).parent().prev().removeClass("schovatDiv");
          $(this).removeClass("schovatDiv");
          count++;
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#vyhledavani_kompatibilit_pocet").hide();
      $(".komp").parent().prev().removeClass("schovatDiv");
      $(".komp").removeClass("schovatDiv");

    };

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;

    {
      $("#vyhledavani_kompatibilit_pocet").text(count);
    }

  });
});
```

Is there any way to speed up searching so it won't take like 8 seconds to filter when you write *"Toshiba"* in the search field?

Thanks for any advance or tip. :)

Comment: You may find that it is faster to keep a list of the items in javascript, run the ajax, and output fresh html rather than trying to update the DOM so many times. Or you could use something like react to manage updating the DOM for you. That's just how I would do it, but there's probably a simpler way to get this off the ground.

Comment: If you don't want to make any large changes to this, you could try [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the function to add/remove classes. That way it will only make changes after the user has paused their typing. A debounce time of 300ms may not be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance by rendering not all content, but only visible part.
Then it can work really fast.